# How do I manage multiple, overlapping XMLHttpRequests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on my first AJAX project, and I've started by setting up the following functions:

```
function sendHTTPRequest(callback,filename,data) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = callback;
    httpRequest.open('POST',rootAddress+filename, true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    httpRequest.send(data);

}

function exampleCallback() {

    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            // successful, parse the XML data
        } else {
            // error
        }
    } else {
        // not ready
    }
}
```

This has worked well but I've now gotten to the point where I have more than one simultaneous HTTP request, and my single global `httpRequest` variable isn't cutting it. It seems to me I could use an array, and `.push` a new XMLHttpRequest onto the stack each time `sendHTTPRequest()` is called, but how can I tell my various callback functions which item in the stack to parse? Or is the a better way to handle this process? (I'm using these to handle requests to different pages, with results that need to be parsed differently.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a local variable and a per-request callback, which in turn calls the given callback. The changes required are surprisingly small; see `**` lines:

```
function sendHTTPRequest(callback,filename,data) {
    var httpRequest; // ** Local variable

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    // ** Callback specific to *this* request
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                // successful, call the callback
                callback(httpRequest);
            } else {
                // error, call the callback -- here we use null to indicate the error
                callback(null);
            }
        } else {
            // not ready
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('POST',rootAddress+filename, true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    httpRequest.send(data);
}

function exampleCallback(xhr) {

    if (xhr) {
        // successful, parse the XML data, for instance
        var x = xhr.responseXML;
    } else {
        // not ready
    }
}
```

You could have it give the callback more information (for instance, the `filename` and `data` arguments).

If you use promises, you could have `sendHTTPRequest` return a promise instead of accepting a direct callback.

Comment: I know we're supposed to avoid "thank you" posts, but this is really incredibly helpful and informative. Thanks for your clear explanation and improvements!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
> ```

Don't use a global. Use a local variable.

> ```
> if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
> ```

Don't use a global. Event handlers are called in the context of the object on which they fire. Use `this`.